# Set right padding for LeftDrawable in EditText

Tags: android

How to define right padding for `LeftDrawable` in `EditText`?

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
```

This sets padding for all sides, but I want for just one side, something like:

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a drawable XML with the image you want and add there the paddings you want, then you can use this drawable at the EditText

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:bottom="5px"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        android:left="10px"
        android:right="10px"
        android:top="5px" />


</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have about 300 images. Need to be done programatically